# email successfully sent to my email account but browser freezes at sendemail.php page

Tags: php, html, ajax, email

I get the email as i set to my code  , but when the script  executed , browser redirects me to sendemail.php and  freezes there.

here is the screenshot 
[sendemail.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L45x1.jpg)

here is the code for FORM  element to my html file

```html
 </section> -->
  <section id="contact">
    <div id="contact-us" class="parallax">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="heading text-center col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            <p>Request a service , learn about our services</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-form wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post"  enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="sendemail.php">
                <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms" id="message_form">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required="required">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required="required">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required="required"></textarea>
                </div>                        
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn-submit" name="submit" id="submit">Send Now</button>
                </div>
              </form>   
              
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="contact-info wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                <p></p>
                <ul class="address">
                 
                  <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <span> Phone:</span> my phone  </li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <span> Email:</span><a href="mailto:info@mydomain.com"> info@mydomain.com</a></li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> <span> Website:</span> <a href="#">www.mydomain.com</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>                            
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>        
  </section><!--/#contact-->
```

And here is the script that calls sendemail.php

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#submit').click(function(e) {
          var data =  name : $("#name").val(), 
                            subject:$("#subject").val ,
                            email: $("#email").val(),
                        message: $("#message").val()};
                        console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "sendemail.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(){
     
     alert("it was success");
              
    }
});
</script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

here is the code for sendemail.php

```
<?php 
$msg = 'Name: ' .$_POST['name'] ."\n" 
.'Email :' .$_POST['email'] ."\n"
    .'Subject: ' .$_POST['subject'] ."\n"
    .'Message: ' .$_POST['message'] ."\n";
     mail('info@mydomain.com','You have one message from santoriginal.com', $msg); ?>
```

WHere is the wrong to my code ?

Thanks

Comment: yes, bscous of you forgot to give header. try to give header.

Comment: You have already asked this same question previously.

Comment: i tried header 2 Balvant Ahir but the result is thesame

Answer (score 1):

Your browser doesn't freeze, `sendemail.php` has no content.

An AJAX call to `sendemail.php` will not redirect you to `sendemail.php`, but your form does.

Try using `return false;` in the `$('#submit').click();` this way the form is not submitted.

Comment: thanks friend for your reply , but nothing happens with return false;

Comment: That's exactly the idea: No form submission, but the AJAX call still calls `sendemail.php`. If you want something to happen, redirect the form to something other that `sendemail.php`.

Comment: that was the problem friend.Thanks a lot for your help .